# How can I bootstrap the innermost array of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, statistics-bootstrap

I have a numpy array of these dimensions

`data.shape (categories, models, types, events): (10, 11, 50, 100)`

Now I want to do `sample with replacement` in the innermost array (100) only. For a single array such as this:

`data[0][0][0]`

`array([ 40.448624 ,  39.459843 ,  33.76762  ,  38.944622 ,  21.407362 ,
        35.55499  ,  68.5111   ,  16.512974 ,  21.118315 ,  18.447166 ,
        16.026619 ,  21.596252 ,  41.798622 ,  63.01645  ,  46.886642 ,
        68.874756 ,  17.472408 ,  53.015724 ,  85.41213  ,  59.388977 ,
        17.352108 ,  61.161705 ,  23.430847 ,  20.203123 ,  22.73194  ,
        77.40547  ,  43.02974  ,  29.745787 ,  21.50163  ,  13.820962 ,
        46.91466  ,  41.43656  ,  18.008326 ,  13.122162 ,  59.79936  ,
        94.555305 ,  24.798452 ,  30.362497 ,  13.629236 ,  10.792178 ,
        35.298515 ,  20.904285 ,  15.409604 ,  20.567234 ,  46.376335 ,
        13.82727  ,  17.970661 ,  18.408686 ,  21.987917 ,  21.30094  ,
        24.26776  ,  27.399046 ,  49.16879  ,  21.831453 ,  66.577    ,
        15.524615 ,  18.091696 ,  24.346598 ,  24.709772 ,  19.068447 ,
        24.221592 ,  25.244864 ,  52.865868 ,  22.860783 ,  23.586731 ,
        18.928782 ,  21.960285 ,  74.77856  ,  15.176119 ,  20.795431 ,
        14.3638935,  35.937237 ,  29.993324 ,  30.848495 ,  48.145336 ,
        38.02541  , 101.15249  ,  49.801117 ,  38.123184 ,  12.041505 ,
        18.788296 ,  20.53382  ,  31.20367  ,  19.76104  ,  92.56279  ,
        41.62944  ,  23.53344  ,  18.967432 ,  14.781404 ,  20.02018  ,
        27.736559 ,  16.108913 ,  44.935062 ,  12.629299 ,  34.65672  ,
        20.60169  ,  21.779675 ,  31.585844 ,  23.768578 ,  92.463196 ],
      dtype=float32)`

I can do `sample with replacement` using this: `np.random.choice(data[0][0][0], 100)`, which I will be doing thousands of times.

`array([ 13.629236,  92.56279 ,  21.960285,  20.567234,  21.50163 ,
        16.026619,  20.203123,  23.430847,  16.512974,  15.524615,
        18.967432,  22.860783,  85.41213 ,  21.779675,  23.586731,
        24.26776 ,  66.577   ,  20.904285,  19.068447,  21.960285,
        68.874756,  31.585844,  23.586731,  61.161705, 101.15249 ,
        59.79936 ,  16.512974,  43.02974 ,  16.108913,  24.26776 ,
        23.430847,  14.781404,  40.448624,  13.629236,  24.26776 ,
        19.068447,  16.026619,  16.512974,  16.108913,  77.40547 ,
        12.629299,  31.585844,  24.798452,  18.967432,  14.781404,
        23.430847,  49.16879 ,  18.408686,  22.73194 ,  10.792178,
        16.108913,  18.967432,  12.041505,  85.41213 ,  41.62944 ,
        31.20367 ,  17.970661,  29.745787,  39.459843,  10.792178,
        43.02974 ,  21.831453,  21.50163 ,  24.798452,  30.362497,
        21.50163 ,  18.788296,  20.904285,  17.352108,  41.798622,
        18.447166,  16.108913,  19.068447,  61.161705,  52.865868,
        20.795431,  85.41213 ,  49.801117,  13.82727 ,  18.928782,
        41.43656 ,  46.886642,  92.56279 ,  41.62944 ,  18.091696,
        20.60169 ,  48.145336,  20.53382 ,  40.448624,  20.60169 ,
        23.586731,  22.73194 ,  92.56279 ,  94.555305,  22.73194 ,
        17.352108,  46.886642,  27.399046,  18.008326,  15.176119],
      dtype=float32)`

But since there is no `axis` in np.random.choice, how can I do it for all arrays (i.e. (categories, models, types))? Or is looping through it the only option?

Comment: Is shuffling okay?

Comment: @coldspeed It needs to be `sampling with replacement`. But if you have a `shuffling` example/answer, please do provide, as I will test both at a later stage. Thanks!

Comment: In `numpy`, the first dimension is outermost, last inner.  Also, where possible we index with one set of [], e.g. `arr[0,0,0,:]` should produce a (100,) shape array.  Transposing to put that size 100 axis first (outermost) might be a good idea.

Comment: I'd try applying `choice` to a 1d indexing array, e.g.  `idx = np.random.choice(100, size); arr[:,:,: idx]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much for the correction. I have updated the question.

Comment: @hpaulj Cool trick. Let me try that as well.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what output you're hoping to get? For instance, are you looking for a resampled array of shape `(10, 11, 50, N)`? Should the contents of, for example, `resampled[5,5,5,:]` be sampled only from `original[5,5,5,:]`, or can they be taken from anywhere in `original`?

Comment: @hpaulj I have attached the answer. Looks like correct...Please let me know if you think something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest/simplest answer turns out to be based on indexing a flattened version of your array:

```
def resampFlat(arr, reps):
    n = arr.shape[-1]

    # create an array to shift random indexes as needed
    shift = np.repeat(np.arange(0, arr.size, n), n).reshape(arr.shape)

    # get a flat view of the array
    arrflat = arr.ravel()
    # sample the array by generating random ints and shifting them appropriately
    return np.array([arrflat[np.random.randint(0, n, arr.shape) + shift] 
                     for i in range(reps)])
```

Timings confirm that this is the fastest answer.

### Timings

I tested out the above `resampFlat` function alongside a simpler `for` loop based solution:

```
def resampFor(arr, reps):
    # store the shape for the return value
    shape = arr.shape
    # flatten all dimensions of arr except the last
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])
    # preallocate the return value
    ret = np.empty((reps, *arr.shape), dtype=arr.dtype)
    # generate the indices of the resampled values
    idxs = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[-1], (reps, *arr.shape))

    for rep,idx in zip(ret, idxs):
        # iterate over the resampled replicates
        for row,rowrep,i in zip(arr, rep, idx):
            # iterate over the event arrays within a replicate
            rowrep[...] = row[i]

    # give the return value the appropriate shape
    return ret.reshape((reps, *shape))
```

and a solution based on Paul Panzer's fancy indexing approach:

```
def resampFancyIdx(arr, reps):
    idx = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[-1], (reps, *data.shape))
    _, I, J, K, _ = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, (0, *arr.shape[:-1], 0)))]

    return arr[I, J, K, idx]
```

I tested with the following data:

```
shape = ((10, 11, 50, 100))
data = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
```

Here's the results from the array flattening approach:

```
%%timeit
resampFlat(data, 100)

1.25 s ± 9.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

the results from the `for` loop approach:

```
%%timeit
resampFor(data, 100)

1.66 s ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and from Paul's fancy indexing:

```
%%timeit
resampFancyIdx(data, 100)

1.42 s ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Contrary to my expectations, `resampFancyIdx` beat `resampFor`, and I actually had to work fairly hard to come up with something better. At this point I would really like a better explanation of how fancy indexing works at the C-level, and why it's so performant.

Comment: Thank you. Several new concepts in your code for me. Prob will take a while to understand everything. Though the shape looks good.

Comment: @maximusdooku my first answer was a little hacky, so I came up with something better. Hopefully it'll be a little easier to understand, too

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the indices of your samples and then apply fancy indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> (categories, models, types, events) = (10, 11, 50, 100)
>>> data = np.random.random((categories, models, types, events))
>>> N_samples = 1000
>>> 
>>> idx = np.random.randint(0, events, (categories, models, types, N_samples))
>>> I, J, K, _ = np.ogrid[:categories, :models, :types, :0]
>>> 
>>> resampled = data[I, J, K, idx]
```

A small explicit example for concreteness. The fields are labeled with "category" (A or B), "model" (a or b) and "type" (1 or 2) to make it easy to verify that sampling does preserve these.

```
>>> I, J, K, L = np.ix_(*(np.array(list(x), 'O') for x in ('AB', 'ab', '12', 'xyzw')))
>>> data = I+J+K+L
>>> data
array([[[['Aa1x', 'Aa1y', 'Aa1z', 'Aa1w'],
         ['Aa2x', 'Aa2y', 'Aa2z', 'Aa2w']],

        [['Ab1x', 'Ab1y', 'Ab1z', 'Ab1w'],
         ['Ab2x', 'Ab2y', 'Ab2z', 'Ab2w']]],


       [[['Ba1x', 'Ba1y', 'Ba1z', 'Ba1w'],
         ['Ba2x', 'Ba2y', 'Ba2z', 'Ba2w']],

        [['Bb1x', 'Bb1y', 'Bb1z', 'Bb1w'],
         ['Bb2x', 'Bb2y', 'Bb2z', 'Bb2w']]]], dtype=object)
>>> N_samples = 3
>>> 
>>> idx = np.random.randint(0, data.shape[-1], (N_samples, *data.shape))
>>> _, I, J, K, _ = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, (0, *data.shape[:-1], 0)))]
>>> 
>>> resampled = data[I, J, K, idx]
>>> res
ResourceWarning  resampled        
>>> resampled
array([[[[['Aa1z', 'Aa1y', 'Aa1y', 'Aa1x'],
          ['Aa2y', 'Aa2z', 'Aa2z', 'Aa2z']],

         [['Ab1w', 'Ab1z', 'Ab1y', 'Ab1x'],
          ['Ab2y', 'Ab2w', 'Ab2y', 'Ab2w']]],


        [[['Ba1z', 'Ba1y', 'Ba1y', 'Ba1x'],
          ['Ba2x', 'Ba2x', 'Ba2z', 'Ba2x']],

         [['Bb1x', 'Bb1x', 'Bb1y', 'Bb1z'],
          ['Bb2y', 'Bb2w', 'Bb2y', 'Bb2z']]]],



       [[[['Aa1x', 'Aa1w', 'Aa1x', 'Aa1z'],
          ['Aa2y', 'Aa2y', 'Aa2x', 'Aa2z']],

         [['Ab1y', 'Ab1x', 'Ab1w', 'Ab1z'],
          ['Ab2w', 'Ab2x', 'Ab2w', 'Ab2w']]],


        [[['Ba1x', 'Ba1z', 'Ba1x', 'Ba1z'],
          ['Ba2x', 'Ba2y', 'Ba2y', 'Ba2w']],

         [['Bb1z', 'Bb1w', 'Bb1y', 'Bb1w'],
          ['Bb2w', 'Bb2x', 'Bb2w', 'Bb2z']]]],



       [[[['Aa1w', 'Aa1w', 'Aa1w', 'Aa1y'],
          ['Aa2z', 'Aa2x', 'Aa2y', 'Aa2x']],

         [['Ab1z', 'Ab1z', 'Ab1x', 'Ab1y'],
          ['Ab2w', 'Ab2x', 'Ab2x', 'Ab2y']]],


        [[['Ba1w', 'Ba1x', 'Ba1y', 'Ba1y'],
          ['Ba2z', 'Ba2x', 'Ba2x', 'Ba2x']],

         [['Bb1z', 'Bb1w', 'Bb1x', 'Bb1x'],
          ['Bb2z', 'Bb2x', 'Bb2w', 'Bb2z']]]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain if this is different/better than what I posted and why? Specially with regards to cross-correlations. Looks neat!

Comment: I am not sure I understand this code unfortunately. Is it doing "global" `sample with  replacement` in all events? Because the sampling needs to happen in each 100 event array...

Comment: @maximusdooku I've added a small example, so you can check whether it does what you need. The advantage of this method is that it avoids a python level loop. Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: I am going through every step. But the shape of data changes from `(2, 2, 2, 4)` to 
`(2, 2, 2, 6)`. But I need to generate 6 samples of `(2,2,2,4)` for example...Perhaps I am not understanding the code because of fancy indexing...

Comment: @maximusdooku think about it this way: given `N_samples=12`, Paul's answer would produce the same result as if you took 3 samples of shape `(2, 2, 2, 4)` and then just stuck them together along the last axis. Either approach (one array of shape `(2,2,2,N*4)` vs `N` arrays of shape `(2,2,2,4)`) can produce a correct bootstrap. In any case, I think this answer is a good one. It's similar to hpaulj's, but without the flaw in the math

Comment: @maximusdooku I only just saw your self-answer. Maybe I misunderstood what you require. Do you really want to to sample all categories, models, types en block? With my diagnostic example your code would produce an outcome where all "columns" are constant in the event, i.e. the first column could be something like Aa1y, Aa2y, Ab1y, Ab2y, Ba1y, Ba2y, Bb1y, Bb2y. Re your other remark getting 6 or 4 or 6x4 samples shouldn't require major changes to the logic.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you. Apologies for miscommunication. For each combination of (categories, models, types), I need to `sample with replacement` within that combination. For example, every `types` has `100` events, it needs to remain a total of 100. If the resampled array becomes `(NSAMPLES, 10, 11, 50, 100)`, I think that would be the correct one. Let me think over it more. I am getting confused with some concepts in Python that are new to me.

Comment: @maximusdooku I've adapted the second example, so it produces at least the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
databoot = []
for i in range(5):
    idx = np.random.choice(100, 100)
    databoot.append(data[:,:,:,idx])
```

- shape of `databoot` -> (5, 10, 11, 50, 100)
- shape of `data` -> (10, 11, 50, 100)

Comment: @hpaulj came up with a nicely efficient/parsimonious answer, but I don't think it's 100% mathematically correct. Basically, if there's any correlations between the `events` in different `(categories, models, types)`, the above answer may bias your resampled array, as well as the results from your bootstrap

Comment: @tel I would love to see a more correct answer...If you know how to, please do post.