# Swapping the dimensions of a numpy array using Ellipsis?

Tags: python, numpy, ellipsis

This code is **swapping** first and the last channels of an **RBG** image which is loaded into a Numpy array:

```py
img = imread('image1.jpg')

# Convert from RGB -> BGR
img = img[..., [2, 1, 0]]
```

While I understand the use of **Ellipsis** for slicing in Numpy arrays, I couldn't understand the use of Ellipsis here. Could anybody explain what is exactly happening here?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for all but the last diimension.

Comment: This is more of a reversal or flip of one dimension, not a swap of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

`img[..., [2, 1, 0]]` produces the same result as taking the slices `img[:, :, i]` for each `i` in the index array `[2, 1, 0]`, and then stacking the results along the last dimension of `img`. In other words:

```
img[..., [2,1,0]]
```

will produce the same output as:

```
np.stack([img[:,:,2], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,0]], axis=2)
```

The ellipsis `...` is a placeholder that tells numpy which axis to apply the index array to. Without the `...` the index array will be applied to the first axis of `img` instead of the last. Thus, without `...`, the index statement:

```
img[[2,1,0]]
```

will produce the same output as:

```
np.stack([img[2,:,:], img[1,:,:], img[0,:,:]], axis=0)
```

## What the docs say

This is an example of what the [docs call "Combining advanced and basic indexing"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing):

> When there is at least one slice (:), ellipsis (...) or np.newaxis in the index (or the array has more dimensions than there are advanced indexes), then the behaviour can be more complicated. It is like concatenating the indexing result for each advanced index element.

It goes on to describe that in this

> case, the dimensions from the advanced indexing operations [in your example `[2, 1, 0]`] are inserted into the result array at the same spot as they were in the initial array (the latter logic is what makes simple advanced indexing behave just like slicing).

## The 2D case

The docs aren't the easiest to understand, but in this case it's not too hard to pick apart. Start with a simpler 2D case:

```
arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Using the same kind of advanced indexing with a single index value yields:

```
arr[:, [1]]

array([[ 1],
       [ 4],
       [ 7],
       [10]])
```

which is the 1st column of `arr`. In other words, it's like you yielded all possible values from `arr` while holding the index of the last axis fixed. Like @hpaulj said in his comment, the ellipsis is there to act as a placeholder. It effectively tells numpy to iterate freely over all of the axes except for the last, to which the indexing array is applied.

You can use also this indexing syntax to shuffle the columns of `arr` around however you'd like:

```
arr[..., [1,0,2]]

array([[ 1,  0,  2],
       [ 4,  3,  5],
       [ 7,  6,  8],
       [10,  9, 11]])
```

This is essentially the same operation as in your example, but on a 2D array instead of a 3D one.

You can explain what's going on with `arr[..., [1,0,2]]` by breaking it down to simpler indexing ops. It's kind of like you first take the return value of `arr[..., [1]]`:

```
array([[ 1],
       [ 4],
       [ 7],
       [10]])
```

then the return value of `arr[..., [0]]`:

```
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

then the return value of `arr[..., [1]]`:

```
array([[ 2],
       [ 5],
       [ 8],
       [11]])
```

and then finally concatenated all of those results into a single array of shape `(*arr.shape[:-1], len(ix))`, where `ix = [2, 0, 1]` is the index array. The data along the last axis are ordered according to their order in `ix`.

One good way to understand exactly the ellipsis is doing is to perform the same op without it:

```
arr[[1,0,2]]

array([[6, 7, 8],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

In this case, the index array is applied to the first axis of `arr`, so the output is an array containing the `[1,0,2]` rows of `arr`. Adding an `...` before the index array tells numpy to apply the index array to the last axis of `arr` instead.

## Your 3D case

The case you asked about is the 3D equivalent of the 2D `arr[..., [1,0,2]]` example above. Say that `img.shape` is `(480, 640, 3)`. You can think about `img[..., [2, 1, 0]]` as looping over each value `i` in `ix=[2, 1, 0]`. For every `i`, the indexing operation will gather the slab of shape `(480, 640, 1)` that lies along the `i`th index of the last axis of `img`. Once all three slabs are collected, the final result will be the equivalent of concatenating along their last axis (and in the order they were found).

#### notes

- The only difference between `arr[..., [1]]` and `arr[:,1]` is that `arr[..., [1]]` preserves the shape of the data from the original array.
- For a 2D array, `arr[:, [1]]` is equivalent to `arr[..., [1]]`. `:` acts as a placeholder just like `...`, but only for a single dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I covered most of the basics (at least in terms of how the output value is generated), but are there any interesting details that I'm missing?]

Comment: @hpaulj Also, do you know of any good docs/tutorials that cover the full capabilities of the advanced indexing syntax? I've read the [advanced indexing section in the official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), but it doesn't seem to cover most of the possibilities. For example, I saw this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236313/425458) the other day that uses indexing with `np.ogrid` to resample a 4D array in a structured fashion. Sadly, I still have only the barest inkling of how it actually works.